# nginx some ciphers ciphers not offered

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I am using the official nginx:1.15.5 image with the following settings:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256;
```

The handshake with some ciphers fails:

```
openssl s_client -cipher "$cipher" -connect $SERVER
```

Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)

I attached into the nginx container and checked:

`openssl ciphers` and the cipher mentioned above was within the output.

I am running out of ideas, what could be the reason that the handshake with some ciphers both configured in `nginx` and provided by `openssl` fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA ciphers need a certificate with an RSA public key and ECDSA ciphers need a certificate with an ECC public key. Likely you only have a certificate with an RSA public key (still most common) and thus only the RSA ciphers will work but not the ECDSA ciphers.